# Use Tor as Proxy for Internet

Tags: relays, exit-relays, proxy

I want to use Tor as a proxy. Or more specifically reroute my Internet traffic from for example my browser over Tor to change my location.

I found out you can set entry and exit nodes by country if you enter `ExitNodes {us} StrictNodes 1` into your `torrc` file.

I did search on google, but found nothing of use to me.
Also, it doesn't matter if Tor runs on another Computer, I just want to reroute traffic.

Comment: Which os are you using? Have you looked into proxychain?

Comment: @AvivLo I wanted to use a Linux Based Distro. I'm going to look into proxychain, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called [`torctl`](https://github.com/BlackArch/torctl) which lets you do exactly that.
It is written in bash however, so you can only use it on Linux/OSX.

By editing your `torrc` file, you are able to spoof your location.
e.g. append `ExitNodes {us},{ca}` to your `torrc`.